# R hist() and qplot(geom="histogram") are inconsistent

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, p-value

I am experimenting with some simulated p-value distributions.

When plotting my data with `hist()` the result looks as expected. The p-values are uniformly distributed and there is a peak close to zero (the 'signal').

```
data = read_tsv("./data_vector.tsv")
hist(data$p_values, breaks = seq(0, 1, by=1/30))
```

[image]

However, when doing the same with ggplot/qplot, the peak at the left is missing:

```
qplot(data$p_values, geom="histogram", bins=30)
```

[image]

**What did I get wrong? I would have expected the two commands to be equivalent.**

**Data & Code:**
My input data as well as a Rmarkdown-report are available from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/grst/76c0cc6856e95f44442766a51fd76fb0)

Comment: Just specify the `breaks=` to `geom_histogram()` as well: `ggplot(data, aes(x=p_values)) + geom_histogram(bins=30, breaks = seq(0, 1, by=1/30))`

Comment: I works... but how is that different from setting bins=30? Or rather: what happens to my peak to the left when using default parameters?

Comment: The short answer is that histogram binning is way more subtle & complicated than seems reasonable. Sort of like calculating a quantile. (Read `?quantile`.)

Comment: This is what ggplot uses as bin by default with your data `ggplot2:::bin_breaks_bins(range(data$p_values), 30)`. it doesn't know the min/mad so it's splitting up the lowest bin going outside the 0/1 range. The right side of the bin is at 0.03333 for your hist, and 0.017227 for ggplot.

Comment: Thanks, that's the explanation I was looking for!